# Terraforming Cloudfunctions that need compute.instances permissions

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I have a [google_cloudfunctions_function](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/cloudfunctions_function.html) aka GCP cloud function that labels instances which is hitting a `googleapi: Error 403: Required 'compute.instances.get' permission for`... error.

After research why I get this permission error I found [cloudfunctions_cloud_function_iam](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/cloudfunctions_cloud_function_iam.html) and other references saying that I need to setup a service account with required permissions? Idk how to do this **with Terraform**, and I can't find any examples on Github search.

On other "serverless" systems I would simply add the permissions it needs, e.g. `compute:*` but I am struggling to figure out how to do this within [my Terraform script](https://github.com/kaihendry/gcp-label/blob/master/main.tf). Any pointers please?

Answer (score 0):

Please review following link [1] which outline how to granting roles to service accounts.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/granting-roles-to-service-accounts#granting_access_to_a_service_account_for_a_resource

Comment: You may need an additional permission. I have found a youtube link that might be useful.https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O05KkBlAuFg

Comment: Actually the compute.instances.get permission is embedded in the Editor role as mentioned in https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/permissions-reference. In order to narrowing down the issue, please create a dedicated service account and call it by Terraform.